# Linux sudo command error is not locale specific

Tags: linux, sudo, locale

I am using RedHat Linux 6.4 server, I set locale to ro_RO. If we connect with `sudo` user to Linux machine and execute any invalid command then it shows language specific error but we append `sudo` to invalid command then it shows error in English language. I need to get the locale specific language using `sudo` command.

```
 -sh-4.1$ asdfsadf
-sh: asdfsadf: comand▒ neg▒sit▒
 -sh-4.1$ sudo asdf
[sudo] password for ajit:
 sudo: asdf: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

It is locale-specific, but there are not any Romanian translations for `sudo`, sorry.  They need to be written.

https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/tip/po

On a running system, see `ls /usr/share/locale/*/LC_MESSAGES/sudo*`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what (most of) the env_keep settings provided by distros e.g. Fedora do.  (I've limited the following to locale and color settings):

```
# /etc/sudoers
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS"
```

Comment: I have following setting but still has issue: Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"